# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/serializer/StringDecoder Exception while streaming kafka from Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to read the kafka streaming data from spark streaming application; while in the process of reading data I am getting following exception:

16/12/24 11:09:05 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/serializer/StringDecoder
    at com.inndata.RSVPSDataStreaming.KafkaToSparkStreaming.main(KafkaToSparkStreaming.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

Here is my versions info:

**spark: 1.6.2**

**kafka: 0.8.2**

Here is pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11 -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like implicit String Encoder is needed
Try to apply this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
    implicit val stringpEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[String]
```

you can find more about Encoders [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-Encoder.html) and from official Document [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection)

Comment: Use this
Encoder<String> stringEncoder = Encoders.STRING();

find example here in java

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection

Answer (score 0):

You use incompatible and duplicated artifact versions. Remember that when using Spark:

- all Scala artifacts have to use the same major Scala version (2.10, 2.11).
- all Spark artifacts have to use the same major Spark version (1.6, 2.0).

In you build definition you mix `spark-streaming` 1.6 with `spark-core` 2.0 and you include duplicated `spark-streaming-kafka` for Scala 2.10 while remaining dependencies are for Scala 2.11.